# Get camera's current rotation in degrees

Tags: javascript, math, 3d, three.js

I'm using a `THREE.PerspectiveCamera` with `THREE.OrbitControls` for rotation etc.
When I rotate the camera I want to update a symbol on Google Maps to show the direction of the camera.

Trying to get the rotation of (**Y**) in degrees like this:

```
360 / Math.PI * perspectiveCamera.rotation.y;
```

It returns the degrees from `..5..15...180..15..5` then `-5..-15...-180..-15..-5`.

Is there a another way to get the y rotation of the camera in 360 degrees?

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have used `radians * 180 / Math.PI` to convert radians to degrees. More on these conversions [here](http://cwestblog.com/2012/11/12/javascript-degree-and-radian-conversion/).

Or you could add 180 to the angle you are currently calculating to get a range from 0 to 360 :)

Comment: The conversion works fine the problem is the radians I get from camera.rotation.y, when converted It goes from 0 to 90 deg then instead of adding (91, 92, 93...) it removes back to 0 (90, 89, 88...) and then from 0 to -90 deg and so on.

Comment: Yea, I am seeing that issue too. When I increment the camera.rotation.y by something like 0.01 on update, it works great. But when I use the lookAt() function it fails. Got to dig deeper, I am afraid :(

Comment: I found a way to do it by having a look at OrbitControls source. Using  start_move and end_move vars to keep record of the distance and the current rotation in degrees.